# How to set minDate to current date in jQuery UI Datepicker?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

This is my code and it is not working correctly. I want to set `minDate` to the current date. How can I do it?

```
$("input.DateFrom").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true, 
    changeYear: true, 
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    maxDate: 'today',
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
        $sD = new Date(dateText);
        $("input#DateTo").datepicker('option', 'minDate', min);
    }
```

Comment: Where did `min` magically come from in your code? Surely you want to pass `$sD` instead.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist maybe global variable?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

You can specify minDate as today by adding `minDate: 0` to the options.

```
$("input.DateFrom").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    ...
});
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/2CZtV/

**Docs**: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max

Answer (score 21):

You can use the `minDate` property, like this:

```
$("input.DateFrom").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true, 
    changeYear: true, 
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    minDate: 0, // 0 days offset = today
    maxDate: 'today',
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
        $sD = new Date(dateText);
        $("input#DateTo").datepicker('option', 'minDate', min);
    }
});
```

You can also specify a date, like this:

```
minDate: new Date(), // = today
```

Answer (score 9):

Use this one :

```
 onSelect: function(dateText) {
                 $("input#DateTo").datepicker('option', 'minDate', dateText);
            }
```

This may be useful :
http://jsfiddle.net/injulkarnilesh/xNeTe/

Answer (score 4):

minDate property for current date works on for both -> minDate:"yy-mm-dd" or minDate:0

Answer (score 4):

can also use:

```
$("input.DateFrom").datepicker({
    minDate: 'today'
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I set starting date using this method, because aforesaid or other codes didn't work for me

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#dateFrm').datepicker('setStartDate', new Date(yyyy, dd, MM));
 });
```

Comment: None of the answers worked except this one. Thank you. and for max date just changed it to ('setEndDate', ...)

Answer (score 4):

**Set minDate to current date in jQuery Datepicker :**

```
$("input.DateFrom").datepicker({
    minDate: new Date()
});
```

Comment: Not sure if this adds anything to the already posted answers.

Comment: Code answers should be accompanied by an explanation. Just dropping a chunk of code does nothing to help the OP understand your solution.

Comment: `minDate: 0` is better for performance as it doesn't require an instantiation of a Date object

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#from_date").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: false,
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: '+ 1 month',
    onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
        $('#to_date').datepicker('option', 'minDate', selectedDate);
    }
});

$("#to_date").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: false,
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: '+ 1 month'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input id="from_date" class="datepicker" type="text" placeholder="DD-MM-YY" readonly />

<input id="to_date" class="datepicker" type="text" placeholder="DD-MM-YY" readonly />
```