# How to edit jquery datepicker so that it can selected from current day?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

With that code you can select the days that already passed(like 1 Feb.)

```
$(function() {
$( "#from" ).datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
  numberOfMonths: 1,
  onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
    $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
  }
});
$( "#to" ).datepicker({
  defaultDate: "+1w",
  numberOfMonths: 1,
  onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
    $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
  }
});
});
```

What do I have to add/edit here so that user can select only from current date on and later..
Thanx!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set minDate to current date in jquery date picker?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810602/how-to-set-mindate-to-current-date-in-jquery-date-picker)

Comment: Can be said.. I couldn't find that topic in search though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
("#from").datepicker({minDate: 0});
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2CZtV/)**

Note: using `minDate` you can allow user to select from current date

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
$("#from").datepicker({ minDate: 0 });
```

[minDate DOC Jquery](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate)