# Restricting date picker to start from today only hml

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I have a datepicker from the internet on my system and I want to restrict a user choice so they are only allowed to pick from today on wards.  Below shows my javascript and the HTML form the datepicker is held in is held in.

I tried using minDate : '0' as well as the one that is in the function now.

Any help appreciated.

```js
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', minDate: +0 });
  });
  
  </script>
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
 <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Start Date:</label>
 <div class="col-sm-10">
  <input class="form-control" type="date" id="datepicker" name="start_date" required="required">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems very similar to the following topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810602/how-to-set-mindate-to-current-date-in-jquery-ui-datepicker

Comment: You can try by setting current date as min date in datepicker.. It Should work

Comment: I looked at the other datepicker link before I posted my question but it still wouldn't work for me.  I'm also using Chrome if it makes any difference as I know my datepickr isn't working in Firefox

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try something like this,

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', 
     minDate: 0 
});
```

[demo in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/17z84aw3/14/)

Comment: I inserted this code and it still ins't working.  Would it have anything to do with the version of datepicker I'm using?

Comment: just using 'minDate: 0'. It should be worked. Please check jsfiddle.

Comment: It works in jsfiddle but for some reason it is giving me the jsfiddle datepicker with another datepicker on top of it.  It's behaving very strangely on my code

Comment: What my code is doing is disregaring the whole datepicker function and using a standard datepicker from HTML5

Comment: I saw what you said. the input type should be 'text', not 'date'. Updated jsfiddle.

Comment: I tried the updated jsfiddle and it works in there but I still can't get it to work on my code.  I tried it on IE11, Chrome Version 41.0.2272.118 m and Firefox 35.0.  The java script links I have at the top of my document are - <!-- language:   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>lang-html -->

Comment: Please add all 'http' before 'href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/theme....'. Something like this 'href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/theme'

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="date" min="2000-01-02">
```

date input type has an **min** and **max** attribute to restrict the date selection.

Here you can get today's date in JavaScript and set that value to your date input type. I just gave an example in above code snippet.

Comment: Would that not restrict it to be one date?  If I code in today's date it would work for today but if I went in tomorrow I could select today's date.  I need this to be more dynamic so it recognises today's date as the date the user is logging into the system.

Comment: In JavaScript with var today = new Date() will give you current date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var datePicker = $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        return date.valueOf() >= now.valueOf(); 
    }
});
```