# Disable previous dates of a datepicker according to selected date in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have two datepickers like startdate and enddate.If i select 18th june 2015 in startdate i have to disable previous dates in datepicker to 18thjune2015 in enddate.

Here is my code.

```
 $("#txtstartdate").datepicker({ minDate: 0 });
```

**For end-date:**

```
    var startdate = $("#txtstartdate").val();
    $("#txtenddate").datepicker({ minDate: startdate });
```

Its not working. Can anyone pls help me on this.
thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to set it using the option method on change of start date

```js
$("#txtstartdate").datepicker({
  minDate: 0,
  onSelect: function(date) {
    $("#txtenddate").datepicker('option', 'minDate', date);
  }
});

$("#txtenddate").datepicker({});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input id="txtstartdate" />
<input id="txtenddate" />
```

Comment: Its working..Thank you..:)...But very first time its working..For 2nd time its all dates are disable only except last day of the month.

Answer (score 1):

If you use input tag with attribute `type="datetime-local"` try this:

```js
let today = new Date().toLocaleString('sv-SE').slice(0, 16).replace(' ', 'T');
document.getElementById('someId').setAttribute("min", today);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `yearRange`:

```
$("#txtenddate").datepicker({ 
    minDate: startdate,
    yearRange: '1999:2020', 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `option`

insted of

```
$("#txtenddate").datepicker({ minDate: startdate });
```

Do This:

```
$("#txtenddate").datepicker('option', 'minDate', date);
```

[Change mindate in datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810602/how-to-set-mindate-to-current-date-in-jquery-ui-datepicker)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#txtstartdate").datepicker({
  minDate: 0,
  onSelect: function(date) {
    $("#txtenddate").datepicker('option', 'minDate', date);
  }
});

$("#txtenddate").datepicker({});



<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input id="txtstartdate" />
<input id="txtenddate" />
```

Comment: describe your question please

Answer (score 0):

If **minDate**  is not working, you can try **startDate** it will work definitely.

```
$('#datepicker4').datepicker({
  autoclose: true,
  startDate: new Date() 
 });
```