# how to disable previous selected month in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have two datepickers 1-fromDate and 2-toDate i want If i select month/anydate/year in fromDate then the toDate datepicker to set to nextmonth/anydate/year and disable previous dates.

```
 $("#fromDate").datepicker({
        maxDate: 0,
        onSelect: function (date) {
 $("#toDate").datepicker('option', 'minDate', date);
        }
    });
 $("#toDate").datepicker({
        maxDate: '0'
    });
```

this code is disabling the days not the month

Comment: You mean like the example they have on the jQuery UI datepicker page? https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range

Comment: @j08691 No it'll look something like this example in this link, but i need to disable the whole month http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31204306/disable-previous-dates-of-a-datepicker-according-to-selected-date-in-javascript#

Comment: run the code snippet and see the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$( function() 
    {
        var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",
        from = $( "#from" )
        .datepicker
        ({
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1
        })
        .on( "change", function() 
        {
          to.datepicker( "option", "minDate", getDate( this ) );
        }),
        to = $( "#to" ).datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1
        })
        .on( "change", function() 
        {
            from.datepicker( "option", "maxDate", getDate( this ) );
        });

        function getDate( element ) 
        {
            var date;
            try 
            {
                date = $.datepicker.parseDate( dateFormat, element.value );
            } 
            catch( error ) 
            {
                date = null;
            }
            return date;
        }
    } );
```

Comment: still same result,disabling days no the month

Answer (score 0):

Once used beforeShowDay and onSelect to disable already selected dates

**beforeShowDay** runs before calendar is rendered.
**onSelect** run after user selects a date

make an array to store selected dates , when user selects a date push it in array and **beforeShowDay** callback receives date argument for all days of a month

```
beforeShowDay: function(date){
 ...
 //check date 
}

onSelect: function(date) {
 ...
 //date is user selected value save it for future comparison
},
```

so you can put conditions there check if date in the array returning false for a date makes it disabled and displays as greyed.

https://jsfiddle.net/0g1atvm1/3/

If that helps.