# Date Validation, How to validate entered date with current date

Tags: jquery, html, validation, datepicker, jscript

So I would like my date picker to be validated, giving the user a error script if they pick a day that exceeds the current day. In other words, they must only be able to enter a date that has not yet occured. This is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function checkForm(form)
            {
                var from_hour = document.getElementById('from_hour').value;
                var from_minute = document.getElementById('from_minute').value;
                var to_hour = document.getElementById('to_hour').value;
                var to_minute = document.getElementById('to_minute').value;
                if (from_hour > to_hour) {
                    alert('"From: H:"field cannot be larger than "To: H:" field');
                    return false;
                } else if (from_hour === to_hour) {
                    if (from_minute > to_minute) {
                        alert('"From: M:"field cannot be larger than "To: M:" field');
                        return false;
                    }


                }


            }

        </script>
        <legend>Time Log</legend>
        <form name="form" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return checkForm(this)"  >
            <table>

                <tr>
                    <td>Date:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" required name="date" id="date" /></td>
                <script>
                    $('#date').datepicker({dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"});</script>


                </td>            </tr>
```

Comment: You can use `minDate` option to set the minimum date..

Comment: Where's the PHP in the code? Why tag it with PHP?

Comment: Care to explain how I can add the minDate?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139378/setting-min-date-in-jquery-datepicker

Comment: I had a look, but i want the date to dynamically adjust with each day's pass

Comment: [The docs](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try now and get back to you on the result

Comment: [Some](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267903/jquery-datepicker-changing-mindate-and-maxdate-on-the-fly) [possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375373/jquery-datetime-picker-set-mindate-dynamic) [duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810602/how-to-set-mindate-to-current-date-in-jquery-ui-datepicker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to disable past date as well as current date you can use following statement-

```
  $('#date').datepicker({minDate:1,dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"});
```

Above statement will allow user to choose future date only

Comment: And if i want to add a max date? How would i do that? I tried however it still submits the data to the database