# Date Validation based on current date

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have two date which is Date from and Date to, My problem is, I want Date from can only click/select past dates until the current date, then the Date to can automatically select the current date

Here's the code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Select a Date Range</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
 $(function() {
    $( "#from" ).datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
      defaultDate: "+1  w",
      changeMonth: true,
   changeYear: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      yearRange: '2006:'+(new Date).getFullYear() ,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
    $( "#to" ).datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
   changeYear: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      yearRange: '2006:'+(new Date).getFullYear() ,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
  });
  
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from">
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to">
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate [Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810602/how-to-set-mindate-to-current-date-in-jquery-ui-datepicker).

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work :(

Comment: and it's also different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using maxDate property we can achieve your requirement.

Please set the maxDate as today date for date from Datepicker.

```
$(function() {
   $( "#from" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    defaultDate: "+1    w",
    maxDate: new Date(),
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    yearRange: '2006:'+(new Date).getFullYear() ,
    onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
    $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
  }
});
  $( "#to" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    minDate : new Date(),
    maxDate: new Date(), 
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    yearRange: '2006:'+(new Date).getFullYear() ,
    onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
    $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
  }
}).datepicker("setDate",new Date());
```

});

Hope this will help you.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1421knt5/)

Comment: Thanks!, the Date From is working good, but I want at Date To that it automatically selects the current date.

Comment: @Vista try this fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/1421knt5/3/ 
Now I will set date for Date to date picker using **setDate** method.

Comment: Is it possible, that Date To cannot select anything only the current date? I'm sorry :(

Comment: @vista try this fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/1421knt5/4/.
Now i set minDate and maxDate both are today date for date to Date picker.
I updated, please recheck.

Comment: Thanks! it is what I need :D

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#from" ).datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
      defaultDate: "+1  w",
      changeMonth: true,
   changeYear: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      yearRange: '2006:'+(new Date).getFullYear() ,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
      },
      maxDate: 0
    });
    $( "#to" ).datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
   changeYear: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      yearRange: '2006:'+(new Date).getFullYear(),
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
      }
    }).datepicker("setDate", new Date()).datepicker( "option", "disabled", true );
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 
<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from">
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to">
```

Comment: Thanks! but, is it possible, that Date To cannot select anything only the current date? I'm sorry :(

Comment: Sure. Recheck it, please. Is it what you wanted?

Comment: Thanks! It is almost what I need! :D

Comment: What else? Can you mark the question as resolved then, please?

Comment: I like too, if I only can accept both answers, but balachandar met most of my requirements :(