# Disable past date from actual and enable two days ahead in datepicker in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two html input field using datepicker.

```
<input id="startdate" type="date" onchange="handler(event)" />
<input id="enddate" type="date" onchange="handler(event)" />
```

How javascript looks like to in input **startdate** disable all past dates from today and in second enable only dates +2 days forward from actual.

Comment: are you using jquery ui date picker? you can simply change the max and the min dates http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate

Answer (score 0):

If you are using native `input[type="date"]` you have the attributes `max` and `min`. [See MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#Setting_maximum_and_minimum_dates)

This code set the `min` attribute dynamically as today format.

```js
var today = new Date();
var todayFormat = today.getFullYear() + '-' + leadZero(today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + leadZero(today.getDate());
console.log(todayFormat);

document.querySelector('input').setAttribute('min', todayFormat);

function leadZero(number) {
  return (number < 10 ? '0' : '') + number;
}
```

```html
<input type="date">
```

If you are using jQuery-ui, you can set the `minDate` property to `0` like in this answer: [How to set minDate to current date in jQuery UI Datepicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14810645/863110)